# CXF Asnchronous Service Invocation

Tags: asynchronous, cxf

I'm looking for an example showing how can I configure my CXF project, so that I can call a service method asynchronously; meaning my invocation in the client side doesn't block for the response and when the response is ready the logic will be done. I'm very thankful if somebody can help me

Best

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `@Oneway` annotation on the server side. CXF will handle the request on the server side in a separate thread, so the client won't be blocked and will return immediately after receiving 200 response code and empty response body.

Of course in this case you cannot receive any response (by definition of request-only SOAP operation), which is not an option for you. Unfortunately you're need to implement this by hand using thread pool and future tasks. Fortunately this is very simple since Java 5, start by studying [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) API.